# Docker project structure with submodules

Tags: git, docker

I use microservices in my projects. Each microservice lives in it's own folder and it's own git repo.

All services live in separate docker container. So overall project structure looks like this:

```
project_root/
             microservice1_folder -> Dockerfile, .git, files ...
             microservice2_folder -> Dockerfile, .git, files ...
             microservice3_folder -> Dockerfile, .git, files ...
             docker-compose.yml
```

The problem is that `docker-compose.yml` isn't in any repo. There is no repo I could `git clone` and bring all services up with `docker-compose up -d`.

One could suggest to use submodules but I see no way of integrating them into my workflow.

With current setup I mount each microservice folder into docker, so I can make changes on the fly, commit and so on.

How do I work with submodules?

Answer (score 1):

`project_root` would need to be a git repo. You would then use

```
git submodule add {REPO_NAME} {PATH_TO_REPO}
```

for each of your submodules, which would, in turn, create a `.gitmodules` file in `project_root`.

When you clone `project_root`, you would then need to call

```
git submodule update --init
```

which would pull down the source for each of your submodules.